# Is carbohydrate alcohol inebriant?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-biology, alcohols, carbohydrates

First of all, though I think that my question is related to this society, if you think reverse, tell me to delete the question:

I would like to know if carbohydrate alcohol is inebriant; Can anyone reference me to some valid source?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎ I think I've seen you here before, though. Anyways, I think your Q is on-topic here, but better dealt with in bio.SE. I leave it for community to decide whether it's off-topic or not.

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/can-sugar-alcohols-and-glycerol-in-particular-cause-intoxication

Comment: Thanks dear for everything! however, it is my first night in this society!

Comment: By "carbohydrate alcohol", do you mean alcohol obtained by fermentation? You can also make alcohol by acid-catalyzed hydration of ethylene. It is worth pointing out that a pure chemical, such as ethyl alcohol, will behave the same regardless of how it was produced.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean "do the alcohol groups in carbohydrates such as sugars cause inebriation".

If that is what you mean then the answer is no. Inebriation is a function of some biological effects that are very specific to small alcohols not just to the OH group in a molecule (I suspect that methanol causes inebriation as well as ethanol, but given that it also kills you this is not something i'm willing to test).

Some of the biological effects are based on specific interactions with proteins in nerves, others are gross physical effects (e.g. dizziness is a product of changes to the density of fluid present in the balance organs in your inner ear when the alcohol concentration in the blood is high). The neuromodulation effects are very specific to the size and shape of the whole molecule not just the OH group and the dizziness is a function of the density of ethanol and its ability to circulate in the blood (larger alcohols and other OH-containing chemicals won't do this).

The body has a whole bunch of mechanisms to handle and manage sugars (as they are a primary way of providing fuel to cells). It would be surprising indeed if animals were inebriated by such compounds as they have evolved sophisticated ways to use them as a key part of their metabolism.